# Stuck on defining the function of f(x) recursively

Tags: function, math, recursion

So, I've been looking online for a while now and still haven't found what I was looking so here goes.

The question states:

`f(x) = 2x + 2`. Define `f(x)` Recursively.

I'm just quite puzzled as there is no `f(0)`, `f(1)` or `f(x-1)` function to go by other than the original function.

Any help appreciated thanks.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/ as there is no direct programming aspect to it.

Comment: ok, thanks will try

Comment: Don't know what values x can have, but if they're integers the stopping condition is x = 0 and the return value is 2.  The recursion requires an accumulator, tail recursion, and counting down from x to zero.

Comment: @duffymo all i know is its supposed to be in the form f(x-1)

Comment: Don't forget to say where you got the answer when you turn in the assignment. Plagiarism is generally frowned upon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f(0)    2
f(1)    4
f(2)    6
f(3)    8
f(4)    10
f(5)    12
f(6)    14

f(n + 1) = f(n) + 2
```

^
Theres your pseudo code.

```
def func(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 2
    else:
        return 2 + func(x - 1)
```

Comment: I can post the full answer if you'd like just let me know.

Comment: If you have more information to add, you should add it. I.e. post your "full answer" anyway. Think of it this way: when you answer a question, you're not just answering the asker; you're answering every future person who also has that question. A good answer targets the problem of the question while staying general enough for re-use in various related situations. That's why you link to resources and explain concepts in the abstract before showing an example. You're not just giving a solution; you're giving the asker the tools they need to solve their problem.

Comment: It's general advice. Plus, the time of the comment and the time of the latest edit are four minutes apart, with no comment indicating the edit was the "full answer", nor anything written in the edit summary. Meaning there is no evidence to link that edit with your intent for it to be the "full answer". Did you even think about that before replying?

Comment: The answer was certainly there before you commented. I just give people a chance to get it themselves before giving it.